# How do I not repeat my list comprehension in a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to be unnecessarily fancy with a challenge from codesignal. The problem: "Given a number and a range, find the largest integer within the given range that's divisible by the given number."

I have `l` for left boundary, `r` for right boundary, and `d` for the divisor. If none of the numbers within the boundary are divisible, then the function must return a -1. Otherwise, return the largest divisible number.

Is there a way to avoid repeating the list comprehension?
Is there a better way to do this altogether? (that is equally unreadable and unnecessary of course)

These receive a `NameError: name '_' is not defined`, which makes sense.

```
maxDivisor = lambda l,r,d: _[0] if [i for i in range(l,r+1)[::-1] if i%d==0] else -1

maxDivisor = lambda l,r,d: [i for i in range(l,r+1)[::-1] if i%d==0][0] if _ else -1
```

This works, but I don't want to repeat myself:

```
maxDivisor = lambda l,r,d: [i for i in range(l,r+1)[::-1] if i%d==0][0] if [i for i in range(l,r+1)[::-1] if i%d==0] else -1
```

This works, but is too readable:

```
def maxDivisor(left, right, divisor):
    for i in range(left,right+1)[::-1]:
        if i%divisor ==0:
            return i
    return -1
```

Just to reiterate:
`maxDivisor(-99,-96,5)` should return `-1` and
`maxDivisor(1,10,3)` should return `9`.

Thank you for your help with my unnecessary request.

Comment: "This works, but is too readable", I don't think you understand how coding works. You aren't supposed to write code that is extremely hard to read.

Comment: "too readable" What?

Comment: You could use `filter()` wrapped in `reduce()` (use the initializer to get the `-1`, and do something moderately clever in the reduce function since you want to support negative results*). In my experience many python programmers run away from `reduce()`. (* what does the result of `maxDivisor(-5, -1, 1)` mean?)

Comment: You want codes which are not readable? For whom are you writing it?

Comment: Eventually, when python 3.8 comes out, this could be a use case for the assignment operator `:=` (if I'm not mistaken) - slap a `x:=[list comprehension]` and then return`x[0]`

Comment: By the way, `range(left,right+1)[::-1]` can be written as `range(right+1, left, -1)`. Hope it's a bit less readable ;)

Comment: If you want "unneccesary and unreadable", how about `res = max((x for x in range(l, r+1) if x % d == 0), default=-1) # ths cmmt s bth unnsscry nd unrdbl`

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Even without debating how "practical" this is, what's your criteria for "sufficiently unreadable"?

Comment: OP wants a fancy one liner, that doesn't repeat the list comprehension. I'm not sure why everyone is getting so upset about UNREADABLE CODE!???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not write bad and unreadable code just for the sake of writing bad and unreadable code.<sup>1)</sup>

Instead, I'd suggest using `max` with a generator expression and a default, which does, *and reads*, exactly what you want: Get the max number in this range which is a divisor, or -1 if no such thing exists.

```
res = max((x for x in range(l, r+1) if x%d==0), default=-1)
```

Similar, but maybe closer in spirit to what you were trying, you could use `next` on the filtered reversed range to get the largest such element, or -1 as default.

```
res = next((x for x in range(r, l-1, -1) if x%d==0), -1)
```

If you *really* want to be "fancy", though, how about this: Instead of testing all the numbers, just get the result directly in O(1):

```
res = r - (r % d) if (r - (r % d) >= l) else -1
```

(All of the parens are unnecessary here, but IMHO make it more readable, so this even fulfills part of your requirement.)

---

From your comment, it seems like you are trying ["Code Golf"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), where the goal is to have the shortest code possible. In this case, you might go with the third approach, but use this variant without the ternary `... if ... else ...`. This should also fully qualify for your "unnecessary and unreadable" requirement:

```
x=[r-r%d,-1][r-r%d<l]  # for code-golf only!
```

I will not tell you how it works, though, you have to find this out for yourself.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Unless this is some sort of obfuscated-code-challenge, maybe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The codesignal site counts characters, so my personal goal is to keep that number low (no obfuscation). All of the solutions were great, but the last one is my favorite. I will strive to be this efficient in the future.

Comment: Well the update was much more simple than I thought. You just made a list, size 2, including the largest denominator (r-r%d) and -1. The part that threw me was the second half. I forgot that in Python, True evaluates to 1 and False evaluates to 0 (and None), so you can index through the list using them. That part took me a while to figure out, very clever though thanks!!!